# 'Not a whitelisted origin' error with Azure Mobile Services Authentication

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to create a demo site using Azure Mobile Services. I started with the HTML/JavaScript sample app available in the Mobile Services portal. I added the authentication exactly as explained in the documentation.

When the JavaScript on my index.html page is trying to authenticate against Facebook, I get a new browser window that shows the following error:
{"code":401,"error":"Error: Not a whitelisted origin: https://mysite.azurewebsites.net"}

The address bar for this error window is the following:
https://mysite.azure-mobile.net/login/facebook?completion_type=postMessage&completion_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.azurewebsites.net

The line of client-side JavaScript where the execution is going when this happens is the following:

```
function logIn() {
    client.login("facebook").then(refreshAuthDisplay, function (error) {
        alert(error);
    });
}
```

I think I have done everything according to the tutorial, and set up the facebook app correctly.

I peculiar thing is that I think this problem is transient. Sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't. When it's happening, it doesn't matter how many times I try in succession, it never works. However, at some point, I got the authentication in my demo app working as it should, and was happy. After a couple of days, I return to working with this demo app without touching anything in the meanwhile, and suddenly I get this error.

From the URL giving the error message it seems that this error comes from the Mobile Services in Azure itself. It's not coming from my app, and it's not coming from Facebook.

Any help in solving this is much appreciated!

Comment: Is your app hosted on the web somewhere? Or on a localhost?

Comment: Following-up to @arthurakay's question, is the host where your app is hosted listed in the "cross-origin resource sharing (cors)" session of the **configure** page in the Azure portal?

Comment: Thanks @carlosfigueira, your comment solved my problem! If you want to post is as answer, I can properly mark it as answer. I was not aware of this configuration option. As a feedback to Mobile Services developers I should say that this config is missing from the authentication tutorial and also the error message.

Comment: Thanks, I'll notify the product team to add that information to the tutorial.

Comment: BTW, the information can be found at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-html/, but I'll notify the team to add a note to the other tutorials as well.

Answer (score 3):

To make sure that your mobile service can be accessed from web sites deployed on different domains, you need to add your host in the *cross-origin resource sharing (cors)* session in the **configure** page in the Azure Mobile Services portal.